# how to connect to server using filezilla to uplaod files

Tags: file-upload, filezilla

hi am having the following details, but i was not known which one to be used as host, username and password can someone help me please thanks

```
Domain Name: test.sto.ustravel.in 
IP:  65.49.80.132
Account: ustravels
Admin/SFTP/Shell Password: hn5ddzxnhh
MySQL Password: 759aquqhkk
Server: ust.het.in
```

but i was not known which one to be used as host, username and password can someone help me please thanks. am not able to connect to server to transfer my files. someone help me please

Answer (score 0):

You should ask your server-hosting-support.

We can only speculate, which is maybe the username.

Maybe the name is your Account and the password is the Password from Admin

Comment: Status: Waiting to retry...
Status: Resolving address of sto.ustravel.in
Status: Connecting to 65.49.80.132:21...
Error: Connection timed out
Error: Could not connect to server whenevr am connecting am getting error as above

Comment: i tried to connect via ssh

    EDVs-MacBook-Pro:~ sss$ ssh ustravels@65.49.80.132
    ustravels@65.49.80.132's password: 

And i got asked for the password. Maybe there you can search after connect in the /etc/passwd for a ftp-user